# MySQL Get a selection if not available get other

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization

Is it possible to get a subset form table if the subset is not enough get other

```
product Table
---------------------------
Product_ID | Catgory_ID
--------------------------
1          |1
2          |2
3          |1
4          |3
5          |7
6          |8
7          |9
8          |4
9          |2
10         |1
11         |7
12         |1
13         |6
14         |5
15         |4
```

I always want 4 item in result

Now I want to get 4 product from category 1.

I can get `select * from product where Catgory_ID = 1 limit 4`

Now I want 4 product from Caregory 2, but only 2 product are there with caregory 2, so what I want is I get those 2 products(with category id 2) and get any 2 random product so the total is 4

Can I do that alone in mysql

Comment: **WHAT!!!** Show a random product as if it were in a category that it is not. Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: @RiggsFolly please see below answer!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY CASE WHEN (Catgory_ID = 2) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END LIMIT 4;
```

First you order your table that the needed category is at the top and then u pick 4.

Comment: above worked for me with minor tweak in sql statement `SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY CASE WHEN (Catgory_ID = 2) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END LIMIT 4;`
`

Answer (score 0):

Adding in randomness:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  product
    ORDER BY  (Catgory_ID != 2) + RAND()
    LIMIT  4;
```

Note that boolean expressions evaluate to 0 (false) or 1 (true).